# How to fetch JSON array without any key in Retrofit?

Tags: android, json, retrofit, okhttp

I have a JSON array without any object(key) inside which there are JSON Objects like this :

[
137,
80,
78,
71,
13,
10,
26,
10
]

I tried to parse it but can't find success can anyone suggest me how to parse this type of Response using Retrofit?

Till now what I am done is in the Activity I have done like:-

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) //Here we are using the GsonConverterFactory to directly convert json data to object
                .build();

    Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
    jsonObject.addProperty("userName", "none\\\\Android");

    Call call = api.getUserIcon(jsonObject);

//        Displaying the user a loader with the specific message
        dialog.setMessage("Loading... Please wait...");
        dialog.show();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Integer> call, Response<Integer> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
                

            } else {
                if (dialog.isShowing())
                    dialog.dismiss();
//                    if successfully not added
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure in Success Response", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Integer> call, Throwable t) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failure in Parsing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and in the interface I have:-

```
@Headers({  
        "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8",
        "Content-Encoding:UTF-8",
        "Authorization:Basic bnhvbmVcS2Fua2FTZW46NllrKkNpezc=",
        "appID:Sample Android App",
        "locale:en-US"
})
@POST("Admin/GetRegisteredUserIcon")
Call<List<Integer>> getUserIcon(
        @Body JsonObject body);
```

Comment: show us what have you tried, in your retrofit interface

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA: I have editted

Comment: have you tried using List<Int> since the response is all number?

Comment: @ErwinKurniawanA: After changing i am still getting End of input at line 1 column 1 path $ in the failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Parse such an Array, you can use `JSONArray` as :

```
//For kotlin
val jsonArray = JSONArray(yourArrayString)
//For Java
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(yourArrayString);
```

In case you are extracting it from a `JSON` response which also contain other objects then you can use `JSONObject` with it as:

```
val jsonObject = JSONObject(yourJSONResponse)
val yourJSONArray: String = jsonObject.getString(" Key of Your JSONArray ")
val jsonArray = JSONArray(yourJSONArray)
```

In this case, we are extracting the `Array` string from `JSON` response using its key and then parsing the string as `JSONArray` later.

Remember that, I've used `JSONArray` which is `org.json.JSONArray` instead of `JsonArray` which of `GSON`.

Comment: The JSON array has without a key

Comment: @ANdroid This is why I wrote this -> `val jsonArray = JSONArray(yourArrayString)`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Integer>>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<List<Integer>> call, Response<List<Integer>> response) {
              
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<List<Integer>> call, Throwable t) {

           }
       });
```

Comment: I didn't check. Please check and let me know

Comment: tried with your code. getting the same error as java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to write your own Deserializer? Code below written in Kotlin:

```
       class YourDeserializer: JsonDeserializer<List<Int>>{
    
                override fun deserializer(
                json: JsonElement,
                typeOfT: Type?,
                context: JsonDeserializationContext?         
        ) {
            val jsonArray = json.asJsonObject.get("KeyOfArray").asJsonArray

            var yourArray = mutableListOf<Int>()

            jsonArray.forEach {
                val num = it.asInt
                yourArray.add(num)
            }

            return yourArray.toList()
        }
 }
```

And when you create your retrofit:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(List::class.java,YourDeserializer()).create()  

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)) 
                    .build();

/*Attention: You also need to change your Callback<Integer> to Callback<List<Integer>>, Response<Integer> to Response<List<Integer>> and Call<Integer> to Call<List<Integer>> in your code presented above, so does your fetcher API.*/
```

To learn more, please refer to

Json Deserializer: https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html

Gson Builder:https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.6/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html